# Is it possible to fix this flaw in my algorithm for creating a function tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, tree, symbolic-math

To try and describe it as concisely as possible, what I'm seeking to do is take a polynomial function such as `5*(x^2+3*x)+1` and convert it into a tree with nodes represented by

```
typedef struct 
{
  char fx [];
  char * op;
  node * gx; 
  node * hx;

} node;
```

where the meaning of node above is that the function `fx` on the node can possibly be represented as

```
fx = gx op hx
```

For example, the subfunction `fx=3*x` of the function mentioned above would look like `fx = gx op hx` where `gx="3"`, `op='*'` and `hx="x"`. But, for another example, the subfunction `fx="3"` could not be expressed as `fx = gx op hx` and so its node would look like `{"3",NULL,NULL,NULL}`. The tree of the subfunction `fx=3*x` would therefore look like

```
                     {NULL,'*',     ,       }
                                /       \
                               /         \
                              /           \
                             /             \
                            /               \
                           /                 \
                `{"3",NULL,NULL,NULL}`    `{"x",NULL,NULL,NULL}`
```

I imagined a recursive algorithm for creating the tree to work as follows, with `'^'` denoted the index of the array we are on as we iterate through it, and still using the function `5*(x^2+3*x)+1`.

```
5*(x^2+3*x)+1                        {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
^


5*(x^2+3*x)+1                        {NULL,'*',  , NULL}
 ^                                             /
                                              /
                                        {"5",NULL,NULL,NULL}

5*(x^2+3*x)+1                        {NULL,'*',      ,       }
           ^                                    /        \
                                               /          \
                                              /            \                         
                                             /              \ 
                                            /                \
                                           /                  \
                                          /                    \ 
                                         /                      \
                                        /                        \
                           {"5",NULL,NULL,NULL"}      {"x^2+3*x",NULL,NULL,NULL}

 5*(x^2+3*x)+1                        {NULL,'+',    ,NULL}
             ^                                   /
                                                /
                                               /
                                              /
                                  {NULL,'*',      ,       }
                                              /        \
                                             /          \
                                            /            \                         
                                           /              \ 
                                          /                \
                                         /                  \
                                        /                    \ 
                                       /                      \
                                      /                        \
                           {"5",NULL,NULL,NULL"}      {"x^2+3*x",NULL,NULL,NULL}


 5*(x^2+3*x)+1                        {NULL,'+',    ,NULL}
             ^                                   /
                                                /
                                               /
                                              /
                                  {NULL,'*',      ,       }
                                              /        \
                                             /          \
                                            /            \                         
                                           /              \ 
                                          /                \
                                         /                  \
                                        /                    \ 
                                       /                      \
                                      /                        \
                           {"5",NULL,NULL,NULL"}           {"x^2+3*x",NULL,NULL,NULL}    


 5*(x^2+3*x)+1                        {NULL,'+',    ,    }
               ^                                 /     \
                                                /       \
                                               /   {"1",NULL,NULL,NULL}
                                              /
                                  {NULL,'*',      ,       }
                                              /        \
                                             /          \
                                            /            \                         
                                           /              \ 
                                          /                \
                                         /                  \
                                        /                    \ 
                                       /                      \
                                      /                        \
                           {"5",NULL,NULL,NULL"}           {"x^2+3*x",NULL,NULL,NULL}
```

(except the node `{"x^2+3*x",NULL,NULL,NULL}` would actually built into a tree by recursion ... I don't feel like writing it out above because it would take even more space).

Here's the problem, though. I just realized that my algorithm relies on the fact that the operator precedence is going a certain way. When the algorithm gets to

```
 5*(x^2+3*x)+1
            ^
```

it knows that since the `'+'` sign has lower precedence than the '*' sign that separated the previous two terms `"5"` and `"(x^2+3*x)"`, it should make a new root for the tree and add the subtree for the terms `"5"` and `"(x^2+3*x)"` onto the left-hand side of the tree. If, on the other hand, the function was `5+(x^2+3*x)*1` then when the algorithm gets to

```
`5+(x^2+3*x)*1`
            ^
```

it has to redo the tree (I'm going to  start writing the tree in a more compact way now)

```
      /  *   \
     5      x^2+3x
```

and change it to

```
      /   +  \
     5       /\
            /  \
           /    \
          /      \
     x^2+3x   +   1
```

which is a more complicated process than simply taking the tree and make it left-handside of a new root. In fact, I can't think of an algorithm for "redoing" the tree. Is there one? What does it look like? Any general hints for how I can get past this road block or how to take an entirely different approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simplest would be an in-order binary tree, where the operators are always a root/subroot and the constants/variables are always leaf nodes.  Think I did this exact problem 30+ years ago at University...essentially reverse-polish notation, though I don't think you need to represent the ()'s except if you need to recreate the input string later.

```
           +
         /  \
        /    \
       *      1
     /  \
    /    \
   5      +
         / \
        /   \
       ^     *
      / \   / \
     /   \ /   \
    x    2 3    x
```

Comment: Yea, that's the idea. But what do you mean by an "in-order" binary tree? I'm a little confused by that.